# C function implemented in assembler x86 when parameters are passed by reference

Tags: c, assembly, x86

I am implementing a C defined function in assembler. The function is as follows

```
extern void swapNums(float* one,float* two,float* three);
```

A) swapNums accepts 3 references to a float, and then places the smallest of these 3 values in 'one', the middle value in 'two' and the largest of the three values in 'three'.

I want to know:

1. Which registers are used to store the references to the 3 floats,
   i.e. Is it rsi,rdi,rdx... or is it xmm0,xmm1,xmm3 ...
2. How do I change the value in *one, *two, *three so that i can satisfy A)

I am accustomed to implementing C functions in assembler when the parameters of the function are passed by value. For example when dealing with floating point parameters, I follow the conventions below:

```
section .data

    global <name of function>

<name of function>:
    movss [x1], xmm0 ; move the first parameter into memory location x1
    movss [x2], xmm1 ; move the second parameter into memory location x2
    movss [xNorm], xmm2 ; move the third parameter into memory location x3
```

and then link the object files of the .asm and .c files when creating an executable

Comment: Pointers are passed by value (so just push pointer value onto the stack), you just need to access the variable through indirection from the pointer inside the function body,

Comment: Those are pointers, not references, AFAIK. I think would involve fetching the value at the address contained in the pointer. I am not an x86 assembly expert, though. edit: @Jean-BaptisteYunès, you beat me :)

Comment: What operating system? Windows and UNIX have different ABIs.

Comment: You can also "cheat" a bit, write a function in C like `float testAbi(float *one) { return *one; }` and compile it with assembly listing to see how C would work with that pointer.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès: Both major x86-64 ABIs pass args in regs, not the stack.  But yes, a pointer arg is just a value, passed the same way as an equal-sized integer.  See the [x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info) for links to ABI docs that specify what goes where.  Or just look at where a compiler targeting that ABI puts things.

Answer (score 3):

I've got [the *exact* same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39499039/how-to-work-with-addresses-in-an-assembly-function-called-from-c), and I figured it out.

`rdi` contains the literal address, `[rdi]` will 'point' to the value stored at that address; so the three addresses will be stored at `rdi`, `rsi`, and `rdx` (Linux, and Mac OS/X); or `rcx`, `rdx`, and `r8` (Windows).

So then to move the actual values that need to be compared across to the SSE registers you need to use, `movss xmm0, [rdi]`.

Finally to get the floats back across to the C program, you need to use `movss [rdi], xmm0`: this will move the value of `xmm0` over to where `rdi` is 'pointing' to.

Comment: This is correct for the x86-64 System V ABI.  x86-64 Windows uses the same idea but different registers.  See also http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/x86/3261/calling-conventions

Comment: @PeterCordes; I'm fairly certain (given the context and timing) that we have the same assignment, in which we need to x86_64 yasm in Linux, but for consistency, I've updated my answer to include the Windows registers.

Comment: Yup, looks good.  The biggest problem with the question is that it doesn't specify a platform / ABI / calling convention, so it's not answerable.  (Unless you can take a useful guess, like you did here.  And then it's important to point out this step in the process of coming to an answer.)  TL:DR: more important to mention the calling convention issue than to actually give a solution for both major ones, but showing the difference by example works well, too.

Answer (score 2):

There is no pass by reference in C because there are no references in C. When programming in C don't use the word "reference", forget that it even exists. All values in C are passed by value because they are values, not references which don't exist. Pointers are values, if that wasn't clear. (Strictly speaking, the value of a pointer is a reference to another object so we can't completely forget the word "reference", but that really confuses people when learning C).

When writing x86_64 (your question implies x86_64, not x86 which your title mentions) assembler all pointers are handled exactly the same regardless of the type they point to and in the function call ABI they are passed in the same registers as integer values.

Comment: Most ABIs return large structs by hidden reference.  So even though C has no notion of return by reference, most ABIs do as an implementation detail.  For arg-passing though, usually even large structs are passed by value, copied onto the stack instead of by hidden const-reference.

Comment: Right, I would have say pass values as usual.

Comment: BTW, x86 commonly includes all flavours these days, not just 32-bit x86.  I wouldn't nit-pick over using the less-specific x86 term when someone meant x86-64 specifically.  It's not like they said x86-32 or i386.  Using x86 to mean 32-bit specifically is getting rarer as 32-bit gets more and more obsolete, especially outside the context of a drop-down menu where some options say x86-64 and some only say x86.